# How can I break up a long, multi-step integration test?

Tags: integration-testing, code-organization

I have a really long integration test that simulates a sequential process involving many different interactions with a couple of Java servlets.  The servlets' behavior depends on the values of the parameters being posted in the request, so I wanted to test every permutation to make sure my servlets are behaving as expected.

Currently, my integration test is in one long function called "testServletFunctionality()" that goes something like this:

```
//Configure a mock request
//Post request to servlet X
//Check database for expected changes
//Re-configure mock request
//Re-post request to servlet X
//Check database for expected changes
//Re-configure mock request
//Post request to servlet Y
//Check database for expected changes
...
```

and each configure/post/check step has about 20 lines of code, so the function is very long.

What is the proper way to break up or organize a long, sequential, repetitive integration tests like this?

Comment: This is a claim of ignorance, but have you unit tested each step first?

Comment: @edmastermind29 Well, my unit tests are in separate classes.  Are you saying I should be unit testing my integration tests?

Comment: @Jeff In my experience, an integration test is to see how A, B, C, and D react under circumstances.  By this point, you should have already unit tested A, B, C, and D individually. If you have unit tested the sum of the parts, its time to integrate test the whole. To answer your question, no.

Comment: @edmastermind29 Yes, I have unit tested each piece, and those unit tests are completely separate from this integration test.

Comment: The act of looping your tests is bad practice. Is there anything wrong with your test being long, sequential, and repetitive other than it being such? If not, I would be doubly assured by the end that everything works and relieved after the painstaking experience. In my opinion, I wouldn't break it up. I'm interested to see other opinions on this.

Comment: @edmastermind29 No, there's nothing wrong with it being lengthy other than the fact that I feel like I must be doing it wrong.  This is the first integration test I've ever created, and I'm just not used to seeing ridiculously huge functions like that.  Just seems like there's a better way that I don't know about, but maybe not.  Couldn't find anything applicable when I googled "how to organize integration tests" and such.

Comment: My last project included watching my Sr. Developer write an integration test that took days to write. I was bored out of my mind. He told me if you question shortening your tests, don't.  The good thing about TDD is that once you write the test, you're done. Then, the code is refined from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8923/discussion-between-cfl-jeff-and-edmastermind29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with integration tests (IT) is usually that the setup is very expensive. Tests usually should not depend on each other and the order in which they are executed but for ITs, test #2 will always fail if you don't run test #1 (login).

Sad.

The solution is to treat these tests like production code: Split long methods into several smaller ones, build helper objects that perform certain operations, so you can do this in your test:

```
@Test
public void someComplexText() throws Exception {
    new LoginHelper().loginAsAdmin();
    ....
}
```

or move this code into a base test class:

```
@Test
public void someComplexText() throws Exception {
    loginHelper().loginAsAdmin();
    ....
}
```